# how to definie dataype tuple of lists of touples including lists in ocaml?

Tags: ocaml

I am getting error when I define a type as: `type table = (string * (string * string list) list)`  for encoding this value:

```
let atable = (
  "Student", 
  [
  ("Id", ["2";"4";"7";"9"]);
  ("Name", ["Jim";"Linnea";"Steve";"Hannah"]);
  ("Gender",["Male";"Female";"Male";"Female"]);
  ("Course",["Geography";"Economics";"Informatics";"Geography"
  ])
```

The environment I am using is [this one](https://try.ocamlpro.com/fun-demo/tryocaml_index.html#path%3Dtries) as I had difficulties using cygwin in Windows.

How to define a datatype satisfying the data table student above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your expresion isn't syntactically valid. It's missing `])` at the end.

OCaml infers the types of things, so once you have a valid expression you can ask the toplevel for the type:

```
# let atable = (
  "Student",
  [
  ("Id", ["2";"4";"7";"9"]);
  ("Name", ["Jim";"Linnea";"Steve";"Hannah"]);
  ("Gender",["Male";"Female";"Male";"Female"]);
  ("Course",["Geography";"Economics";"Informatics";"Geography"
    ])]);;

val atable : string * (string * string list) list =
  ("Student",
   [("Id", ["2"; "4"; "7"; "9"]);
    ("Name", ["Jim"; "Linnea"; "Steve"; "Hannah"]);
    ("Gender", ["Male"; "Female"; "Male"; "Female"]);
    ("Course", ["Geography"; "Economics"; "Informatics"; "Geography"])])
```

So the type is indeed `string * (string * string list) list`.

If you still have a problem after fixing the syntax, the problem must be elsewhere. It would be helpful to see a full example along with the specific error you're seeing.

Comment: Error is comming up in this part but I was supposing that root of it was in the datatype I had declared. 

`let rec printTable aTable = match aTable with
      (  )->""
    | (title, [data]) -> "\n"^title^"\n\n"^printTable(data)
    | [(col,cont)::t] -> col^"   "^printTable([t])`